# OData URI as a absolute path instead of segments

Tags: c#, odata

When an OData entity contains a URI property, it converts this property into a array called segments and splits the URI based on the path and removes the base Path of the URI for some reason. I want to ideally have this data outputted as a string or even have the full path in the segments at least.

Expected

```
"FileUrl": "https://example.com/path/to/file.pdf"
```

Actual

````
"FileUrl": {"Segments": ["/","path/","to/","file.pdf"]}```
````

Comment: Assuming you know the scheme and host are fixed, (https and example.com), you can deserialize the json into a matching object, get the Segments out, then use Path.Combine() to join them together. Then attach all parts to get your final URL.

Comment: Sadly the host (and potentially scheme) could change as the server for them can be moved around between the live blob storage we have and an archive one

Comment: Should be returned or included somewhere by the API you're consuming, or as you say, will be impossible to find the file with your given segments.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355510/json-serialization-of-uri-type-in-webapi-2-odata-3-c-sharp-project this might be related.

Comment: I do not think that solution will work any more as ASP .net in the newer framework has moved away from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text instead.